After replacing current image, Image component still shows the old image
In a NextJs 14.2.15 project, I have a problem to showing a copied image over current image. After successful copy operation, in related page and related server component that handle of preview images files, it still shows the old image file.
For example we have /public/assets/tablet/screen.jpg and if a user copy another image with the same filename from /public/assets/mobile/screen.jpg to tablet directory, the copied image replaced successfully on the old file (checked by file explorer) but in the files preview, it still shows the old screen.jpg file even with use export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' (in related jsx server component file) and ctrl + F5 and also "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in browser inspect mode. In related server action that handles copy operation after fs.promise.copyFile(), it runs revalidate([files preview path]) too.
I used <img /> instead of <Image /> with combination ctrl + F5, the problem of showing the copied file solved but I want to use native without doing any refresh by the user to see preview of copied file. Is there any way to disable cache or stronger revalidate after successful copy operation?
files.jsx

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export default function Files({ filenames }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {filenames.map(({ path, name }) => (
        <div key={name} >
            // <Image
            //   src={`/src/to/directory/${path + name}`}
            //   alt=""
            //   fill
            // />

            <img
              src={`/src/to/directory/${path + name}`}
              alt=""
            />

            // handle copy operation on client side
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

paste-item.jsx

'use client' 

export default function PasteItem() {
  function toggleModalHandler() {
    // show modal
    // cancel operation
  }

  function replaceHandler() {
    // call pasteHandler()
  }

  function duplicateHandler() {
    // call pasteHandler()
  }

  async function pasteHandler(replaceConfirmation, duplicateConfirmation) {
    const result = await copyItemAction(
      '/public/assets/tablet/screen.jpg',
      '/public/assets/mobile/screen.jpg',
      replaceConfirmation,
      duplicateConfirmation,
    )

    if (result?.exist) {
      // show a modal to ask what to do
    } else {
      // cancel operation
    }
  }

  return (
    <div> 
      {showModal && (
        <Modal onClose={toggleModalHandler}>
          <div>
            <h3 className="mb-10">There is a file with the same name in destiantion:  what to do?
            </h3>

            <div >
              <button onClick={replaceHandler}>Replace</button>
              <button onClick={duplicateHandler}>Overwrite</button>
              <button onClick={toggleModalHandler}>Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

copy-item-action.js

'use server'

import { access, copyFile } from 'fs/promises'
import path from 'path'
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'
 
export default async function copyItemAction(
  source,
  destination,
  replaceConfirmation,
  duplicateConfirmation,
) {
  const parsedSrcFullPath = path.parse(srcFullPath)
  const confirmation = replaceConfirmation || duplicateConfirmation

  if (!confirmation) {
    const destFullPathWithItemName = path.join(
      destFullPath,
      parsedSrcFullPath.base,
    )
    const itemExistance = await access(destFullPathWithItemName)
      .then(() => true)
      .catch(() => false)

    if (itemExistance) return { exist: true }
  }

  destFullPath = path.join(
    destFullPath,
    duplicateConfirmation
      ? `${parsedSrcFullPath.name}-copy${parsedSrcFullPath.ext}`
      : parsedSrcFullPath.base,
  )
  try {
    await copyFile(srcFullPath, destFullPath)
    revalidatePath('/')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  return null
}


The problem solved by Cache Busting solution.
